# If I have no last name, can I travel on tickets booked with "00" as a last name?

Tags: tickets

I don't have last name in any of my id proof. So while booking tickets my dad has given 00 in place of surname. Because it was mandatory to fill last name.
Will it create any problem for me?

Comment: What kind of tickets? And can you explain why you don't have a last name, and in what IDs specifically? Please [edit] the question.

Comment: Put your first name as the last name as well..

Comment: I think you should contact the airline/site. It is a know problem but developers forgot about it (there is also a good document of w3c about wrong assumptions and wrong form design).

Comment: Relevant: [*Falsehoods programmers believe about names*](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) (#20).

Comment: Under the ICAO travel document standards, as they map to the usual western European concept of given and family names, someone with a single name has a last name but no first name.  There was an Indonesian professor at my university whose first name was in the computer system as `MR`.